# NCrawler behaves erroneous when adding HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, .net, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

System specs: Win7 64 bit, VS2013, .NET 4.0

I am trying to make an application that will crawl a certain page and extract something.

I am using NCrawl for .NET 4.0 sln. I ran NCrawler.demo project and it's working perfectly (extracting all sub-URLs from a specific URL). Now the problem appears:

- when I try to add **HTMLAgilityPack** to the demo so I can interpret the html text. If I just add **HTMLAgilityPack** as a reference to the demo project it makes the app behaves erroneous: it will extract only the first URL and then exit without an error. I also tried NCrawler for .NET 3.5 and the same problem appeared.

Is it a known issue, is there a fix for it?
Thx

Answer (score 2):

After some days of investigating I drawn the conclusion that there was a library conflict on some methods refering HTMLAgilityPack.
I noticed that one of the dependencies projects of the NCrawler(NCrawler.HTMLProcessor) already contains a HTMLAgilityPack reference, and instead of adding HTMLAgilityPack refernce in my project with NUGet as I did, I replaced it with HTMLAgilityPack from this HTMLProcessor project(NCrawler\Repository\HTMLAgilityPack\). 
After doing this, both projects will have the save dll as reference.